# convert character to 12H time format in R

Tags: r

I need to convert a time in character "01:15:55 AM" to time.
I was thinking of using chron library, however I am not sure how to do the format.

```
chron(times = "01:15:55 AM", format = "%I:%M:%S %p")
Error in parse.format(format) : unrecognized format %I:%M:%S %p
```

Any ideas? I'm happy to try other libraries

Comment: time<-strptime("01:15:55 AM", format = "%I:%M:%S %p "), will convert it to a POSIXlt object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `strptime` to parse, and then `format` the result so you can make it into a nice `chron::times` object:

```
library(chron)
times(format(strptime("01:15:55 PM", format = "%I:%M:%S %p"), "%H:%M:%S"))
# [1] 13:15:55
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way of dealing with date and time objects in R is using the `POSIX` functions, such as:

```
> (time.POSIX<-strptime("01:15:55 AM", format = "%I:%M:%S %p"))
[1] "2016-03-31 01:15:55 BRT"
> class(time.POSIX)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

The `strptime` function, along with all others that work with POSIX dates, such as `format` (for printing) accept the format string that you're using.
The problem here is that this data is not a time *per se*, but a date and a time, and the date part is implicitly created as "today". So you can create this time objects in a fixed reference date, say, 2000-01-01.

On the other hand, if you want to use the chron package... they are not compliant with these format specifications. `chron` manual only specifies m, d, y, h, m and s.

You might have to write a wrapper that understands AM/PM and fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 testtime<-("2013-07-21 02:00:01 PM") 
 library(lubridate) 
 ymd_hms(testtime)
[1] "2013-07-21 14:00:01 UTC"
```